# How does a JVM process allocate its memory?

Tags: java, linux, memory-leaks, spring-boot, jvm

I have a little gap in understanding how a JVM process allocates its own memory. As far as I know

```
RSS = Heap size + MetaSpace + OffHeap size
```

where OffHeap consists of thread stacks, direct buffers, mapped files (libraries and jars) and JVM code itself;

At the moment I’m trying to analyze my Java application (Spring Boot + Infinispan) which RSS is **779M** (it runs in a docker container, so pid 1 is ok):

```
[ root@daf5a5ae9bb7:/data ]$ ps -o rss,vsz,sz 1
RSS    VSZ    SZ
798324 6242160 1560540
```

According to `jvisualvm`, committed Heap size is **374M** 
[image]

Metasapce size is **89M**
[image]

In other words, I want to explain **799M - (374M + 89M) = 316M** of OffHeap memory.

My app has (in average) **36 live threads**.
[image]

Each of these threads consumes 1M:

```
[ root@fac6d0dfbbb4:/data ]$ java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version |grep ThreadStackSize    
intx CompilerThreadStackSize                   = 0
intx ThreadStackSize                           = 1024
intx VMThreadStackSize                         = 1024
```

So, here we can add **36M**.

The only place where the app uses DirectBuffer is NIO. As far as I can see from JMX, it doesn’t consume a lot of resources - only **98K**
[image]

The last step is mapped libs and jars. But according to `pmap` ([full output](https://gist.github.com/krestjaninoff/2b027b87e7cad7260259))

```
[ root@daf5a5ae9bb7:/data ]$ pmap -x 1 | grep ".so.*" | awk '{ sum+=$3} END {print sum}'

12896K
```

plus

```
root@daf5a5ae9bb7:/data ]$ pmap -x 1 | grep “.jar" | awk '{ sum+=$3} END {print sum}'

9720K
```

we only have **20M** here.

Hence, we still have to explain **316M - (36M + 20M) = 260M** :(

Does anyone have any idea what I missed?

Comment: There is all the shared libraries of the JVM itself. Try running two JVMs to see how much is added.

Comment: A +1 for the nice research!

Comment: 100% agree with @PeterLawrey. Check what shared libraries is java running by executing `ldd /path/to/java' and 'pmap PID` to see in details what exactly is used by Java.

Comment: It cannot be shared libraries as this is the "Heap size", heap size is Java memory only.

Comment: Also, as you can see "used" is much smaller then the actual heap size. The VM likes to take a lot of memory to increase GC performance. Even of the used heap, a lot of it might be dead objects, that would be collected when a full GC is performed.

Comment: + CodeCache (for dynamically generated code) + GC internal structures (like CardTables) + structures allocated by native libraries (I/O, networking etc.) + .bss segments of JVM and libs

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Approach:**

You may want to use [Java HotSpot Native Memory Tracking (NMT)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr007.html).

This may give you an exact list of memory allocated by the JVM, splitted up into the different areas *heap, classes, threads, code, GC, compiler, internal, symbols, memory tracking, pooled free chunks,* and *unknown*.

**Usage**:

- You can start your application with `-XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary`.
- Observations of the current heap can be done with `jcmd <pid> VM.native_memory summary`.

*Where to find jcmd / pid*:

On a default OpedJDK installation on Ubuntu this can be found at `/usr/bin/jcmd`.

By just running `jcmd` without any parameter, you get a list of running Java applications.

```
user@pc:~$ /usr/bin/jcmd
5169 Main                       <-- 5169 is the pid
```

**Output**:

You will then receive a complete overview over your heap, looking something like the following:

> **Total:**  reserved=664192KB,  committed=253120KB                                           <--- total memory tracked by Native Memory Tracking
>
> - **Java Heap** (reserved=516096KB, committed=204800KB)                      <--- Java Heap
>
>   (mmap: reserved=516096KB, committed=204800KB)
> - **Class** (reserved=6568KB, committed=4140KB)                          <--- class metadata
>
>   (classes #665)                                               <--- number of loaded classes
>
>   (malloc=424KB, #1000)                                        <--- malloc'd memory, #number of malloc
>
>   (mmap: reserved=6144KB, committed=3716KB)
> - **Thread** (reserved=6868KB, committed=6868KB)
>                             (thread #15)                                                 <--- number of threads
>
>   (stack: reserved=6780KB, committed=6780KB)                   <--- memory used by thread stacks
>
>   (malloc=27KB, #66)
>
>   (arena=61KB, #30)                                            <--- resource and handle areas
> - **Code** (reserved=102414KB, committed=6314KB)
>
>   (malloc=2574KB, #74316)
>
>   (mmap: reserved=99840KB, committed=3740KB)
> - **GC** (reserved=26154KB, committed=24938KB)
>
>   (malloc=486KB, #110)
>
>   (mmap: reserved=25668KB, committed=24452KB)
> - **Compiler** (reserved=106KB, committed=106KB)
>
>   (malloc=7KB, #90)
>
>   (arena=99KB, #3)
> - **Internal** (reserved=586KB, committed=554KB)
>
>   (malloc=554KB, #1677)
>
>   (mmap: reserved=32KB, committed=0KB)
> - **Symbol** (reserved=906KB, committed=906KB)
>
>   (malloc=514KB, #2736)
>
>   (arena=392KB, #1)
> - **Memory Tracking** (reserved=3184KB, committed=3184KB)
>
>   (malloc=3184KB, #300)
> - **Pooled Free Chunks** (reserved=1276KB, committed=1276KB)
>
>   (malloc=1276KB)
> - **Unknown** (reserved=33KB, committed=33KB)
>
>   (arena=33KB, #1)

This gives a detailed overview of the different memory areas used by the JVM, and also shows the *reserved* and *commited* memory.

I don't know of a technique that gives you a more detailed memory consumption list.

**Further reading:**

You can also use `-XX:NativeMemoryTracking=detail` in combination with further `jcmd` commands. A more detailed explaination can be found at [Java Platform, Standard Edition Troubleshooting Guide - 2.6 The jcmd Utility](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr006.html#BABEHABG). You can check possible commands via `"jcmd <pid> help"`

Comment: you have typo in `jcmp` ?

Comment: Thanks, will fix this in a moment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried to use NMT and found it very helpful... but I still have a problem :) NMT says that all the memory that I lost belongs to the "Unkonwn" section. When I try to analyze detailed info I found the following: https://gist.github.com/krestjaninoff/a89ee990d94d8fc2917a Do you have any ideas about what happened with this memory? Was it consumed by CMS?

Comment: "NMT in this release does not track third party native code memory allocations and JDK class libraries." (c) Ok, question is closed :)