# What are the recommended settings for the jvm memory of RestHeart?

Tags: memory, jvm, restheart

In the documentation, it does not specify the memory needed for the JVM, in the post on the performance either.

Comment: Please check this answer for your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35555084/finding-memory-requirements-of-java-application

Comment: also consider that RESTHeart runs on java 8 and java 8 uses the metaspace memory model which usually does not need memory tuning at all https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-permgen-metaspace

Answer (score 1):

RESTHeart runs on java 8 and java 8 uses the metaspace memory model which usually does not need jvm memory tuning at all.

we at softinstigate.com usually run restheart with docker and run it on aws ecs service.

we configure restheart threading as follows:

```
# Number of I/O threads created for non-blocking tasks. at least 2. suggested value: core*2
io-threads: 2

# Number of threads created for blocking tasks (such as ones involving db access). suggested value: core*16
worker-threads: 8
```

on aws ecs we set a soft memory limit of 1Gb for the docker container running restheart and we never had a memory issue (even on heavy load)